# depth image from point cloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a point cloud which was obtained from Laser scanning. I need to extract depth images from this point cloud. I want to assume random camera position and set up some camera parameters and get images corresponding to these positions. I found some documentation but this isn't what I need : http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage.
There was a discussion which looked similar to mine here : http://www.pcl-users.org/get-a-2d-depth-image-from-the-pointcloud-td2795083.html but the links posted here are not valid.
Can anybody help me by telling how I should get started with this and also if this is possible.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192680/depth-image-from-point-cloud/) by [Banu Muthukumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20199/banu-muthukumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL´s [RangeImagePlanar class](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_range_image_planar.html) provides what you request (essentially rendering a pinhole camera model image for unorganized point cloud data from novel viewpoints). Specifically, the [createFromPointCloudWithFixedSize](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_range_image_planar.html#a47fc71b0700792cb0b078e9bbbc537f5) is the correct method to use. Once you have converted your cloud to the PCL format, this should work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-03-31**:
links are down